# Web mapping and image gallery RIA application

Tags: google-maps, maps, ria, image-gallery, single-page-application

I am going to create Web portal, which I would like to be some kind of illustrated guide of city. In brief, It would be a union of Web mapping application and image gallery application. User should be able to navigate on the map to find some interesting locations, then user may view images and read articles about these locations.

This application has two important requirements:

1. Has to be RIA / Single Page Application
2. Must support CMS approach, with separated Front-End and Back-Office sections.

I contemplate which technology and framework offers the easiest and most powerful tools to fulfill these requirements with the least of effort. Currently I am thinking about ASP.NET MVC and Google Web Toolkit. What is your opinion? What about other platforms? Or maybe there are existing systems, galleries or CMS platforms which suit to my demands?

Do you know any existing websites with similar architecture and functionalities?